# MongoDB Authentication Error when importing data

Tags: json, mongodb, authentication

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/import/ to import a large JSON file into MongoDB. When entering the following into my command line:

```
mongoimport --db test --collection inventory --authenticationDatabase admin --username <my username> --
password <my password>--drop --file ~\bin\inventory.crud.json
```

I keep getting this error

```
  error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

Does anyone know why this keeps coming up? I am using the correct username/password specific to MongoDB.

Comment: It really just means you're not feeding in the right authentication credentials.

Comment: Are you able connect to the database from other tools like `mongo` shell or Compass using the same credentials?

Comment: @prasad_ yes and it still will not work here?

Comment: What is the syntax you are using when connecting via mongo shell?